# how to set local notifications between 8am and 8pm every day

Tags: swift, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

So I am very new to Swift and I'm currently setting a repeating timer every 30 min after the app was launched, but i would like to only send notification between 8 am and 8 pm. Is it possible to do this without setting a reminder for each specific time?

This is how I'm currently doing this.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error ) in
// enable or disable if needed.
    if granted {
        print("We have permission to send notifications")
    } else {
        print("We don't have the option to send notifications")
    }
}
notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

// The actual notification the user will receive
let notification    = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notification.title  = "You should have some water"
notification.body   = "It has been a long time since you had some water, why don't you have some."
notification.categoryIdentifier = "reminder"
notification.sound  = .default

let trigger     = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (60*30), repeats: true)
let uuidString  = UUID().uuidString
let request     = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you do need to add a notification request for each 30 minute interval in the 8am-8pm window. What is your aversion to this approach? It's a simple for-loop. Instead of using a `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` you would use a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

```
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

let startHour = 8
let totalHours = 12
let totalHalfHours = totalHours * 2

for i in 0...totalHalfHours {
    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = startHour + i / 2
    date.minute = 30 * (i % 2)
    print("\(date.hour!):\(date.minute!)")

    let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notification.title = "You should have some water"
    notification.body = "It has been a long time since you had some water, why don't you have some."
    notification.categoryIdentifier = "reminder"
    notification.sound  = .default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
    notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So if i wanted to give the user the option to change the frequency of the alarms, i would need to change the date.minute? I understand how to use this to change the start and end time, but could you help me understand how to make it more customisable? I would like to be able to customize the frequency of the alarms as well as start and end.

Comment: @PetterBraka I would love to. However, I believe that question is beyond the scope of this one. Perhaps start a new one. But basically, you'd loop over intervals instead of `totalHalfHours` and compute hours and minutes based on the current interval.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think I understand what you mean. I will try and see if I'm able to make it work.