# how to set notifications at custom intervals between custom start and end times

Tags: swift, notifications, intervals, unusernotificationcenter

So i have asked a similar question, but this is outside of the scope of that question. I want to give the user the option to customise when the notifications should start and end; then they would choose the intervals of the notifications.

previous question: [how to set local notifications between 8am and 8pm every day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61592561/13124802)

This is the function i am using now and was provided by @Robert Crabtree:

```
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    let startHour = 7
    let endHour = 23

    let totalHours = endHour - startHour
    let totalNotifications = totalHours * 2

    for i in 0...totalNotifications {
        var date = DateComponents()
        date.hour = startHour + i / 2
        date.minute = 30 * (i % 2)
        print("setting reminder for \(date.hour!):\(date.minute!)")

        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = reminderMessages[randomInt].title
        notification.body  = reminderMessages[randomInt].body

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
        notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing this if you have any other suggestions on how to do this better, please let me know.

```
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    let startHour = 7
    let endHour   = 23
    let intervals = 20

    let totalHours = endHour - startHour
    let totalNotifications = totalHours * 60 / intervals

    for i in 0...totalNotifications {
        var date = DateComponents()
        date.hour = startHour + (intervals * i) / 60
        date.minute = (intervals * i) % 60
        print("setting reminder for \(date.hour!):\(date.minute!)")
        let notification = getReminder()

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
        notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```